# Analysing multiple results of listeners for performance

Tags: jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am using a single jmeter script (.jmx) to generate three listeners results (XML format). The same script of these 3 results have been executed separately

The purpose is to get the average of the response time out of three results files.

Is there any way that we can can compile all these three results files (xml) in Jmeter and get the average on the response time column available in these listeners?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can combine 3 .jtl result files into one using [Merge Results](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) tool
2. The average response time can be calculated using [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line) like:

   ```
   JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv test.csv --input-jtl merged-result.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
   ```

Both plugins can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) (you may need to add [Synthesis Report](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SynthesisReport/) plugin as well)